# Firebird primary keys and EF6 store generated pattern

Tags: entity-framework, firebird

in my database first application (Firebird), the primary keys are not set to identity by default !

how to fix that from the t4 template generation file ?

thanks and good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys are not necessarily identity columns, and Firebird 2.5 and earlier doesn't have identity columns. Instead you simulate it with a trigger and a sequence/generator, but this isn't 'detectable' from a metadata perspective (or at least pretty hard to infer correctly). Identity columns will be introduced in Firebird 3.

For the entity framework client for Firebird to recognize the column as identity, you need to add a comment to the column (in the database!) with the text `#PK_GEN#`, like so:

```
comment on column yourtable.yourcolumn is '#PK_GEN#'
```

See also: [Generated primary key in Entity Framework model from Firebird](http://blog.cincura.net/230841-generated-primary-key-in-entity-framework-model-from-firebird/)

Comment: thanks a lot,it's sort of a hack but it worked just fine , btw i wasn't aware that fb 3.0 support identity columns :)

Comment: @user2475096 Yes, it is a workaround. If you want to find out more about Firebird 3 (in beta, not production ready), look at http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0-0-beta1/